# Elektronik und der Konjunktiv 1

Tags: verb

Wenn ich Apps auf meinem Handy installiere, erscheint

> «Installiere...»

auf dem Bildschirm und heute, als ich versuchte Internet-Radio zu hören, erschien

> «Verbinde»

auf dem Bildschirm. Wieso lautet es nicht

> «[Die App] Installiert» oder
>
> «[Die App] Verbindet»?

Ich dachte, vielleicht spricht das Handy mit mir

> «[Ich] Installiere [die App]» oder
>
> «[Ich] Verbinde [mit dem Rundfunksender]»,

aber das scheint für mich weit hergeholt. Ich denke, dass es wahrscheinlicher ist, dass es Konjunktiv 1 ist, aber ich wüsste nicht, warum Konjunktiv 1 hier nötig wäre.

Frage: Wieso ist es so konjugiert? Konjunktiv 1? Spricht das Handy mit mir, oder sonst was?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Also ich würde es als Aussage aus der Ich-Perspektive verstehen:

> [Ich (die App)] installiere [mich auf dem Handy]

oder

> [Ich (das Handy)] installiere [die App auf mir]

Als Softwareentwickler denke ich, dass es eine etwas fehlerhafte Übersetzung des englischen `Installing` ist

---

Für mich klingt

> [Die App] installiert [sich]

aber auch falsch. Ich würde dann eher

> [Die App] wird installiert

sagen.

Comment: "Installiert" wäre auch ambig, denn es kann auch PPP sein, wie in "es ist bereits installiert".

Comment: Um noch etwas präziser auf thekeyofgbs Frage einzugehen: die o.g. Interpretation ist Indikativ, nicht Konjunktiv. Bitte entschuldigt den Doppelpost.

Comment: Gerade bei Spielen gibt es auch Anzeigen wie "Lädt gerade" für "Loading" - klingt einfach dämlich. "Wird geladen" ist eigentlich auch nicht viel besser. Dann lieber als Satz. Bei einem anderen Handy-Betriebssystem steht übrigens unter dem Icon "Installation", wenn die eigentliche Installation startet (also nach dem Download), da hat man sich für ein Substantiv entschieden.

Comment: `Installiert` könnte auch die Befehlsform 2. Person Plural sein, was natürlich Quatsch wäre. `Installiere` als 2. Pers. Singular aber schon weniger.

Answer (score 5):

Das ist eine Übersetzung des englischen

> Installing
>
> Connecting

Im Englischen kann das

- ein Gerundium sein. Dann sollte es am ehesten durch eine Nominalisierung übersetzt werden: `das Installieren`
- eine Kurzform einer progressiven Zeitform sein (vermutlich present progressive). Dann sollte es am ehesten durch einen Indikativ übersetzt werden, wobei der progressive Charakter durch die 1. Person am stärksten ausgedrückt wird (Imho): `(ich) installiere` oder durch die Konstruktion `am Installieren`
- eine andere Nutzung des present participle sein. Dann sollte es am ehesten durch das Partizip 1 übersetzt werden: `installierend`

Möglicherweise liegt es daran, dass ich schon darauf konditioniert bin, aber persönlich finde ich nur `installiere` und `am Installieren` nicht störend.